# Rayon: why do the two ways of sum give different results?

Tags: rust, rayon

Here I use Rust `rayon` crate to compute the definite integral (left Riemann sum) of a function in parallel:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder;
use std::f64::consts::PI;

fn integral_rayon_test<F>(segments: u32, x0: f64, xn: f64, function: F)
where
    F: Fn(f64) -> f64 + Send + Sync + Copy + 'static,
{
    let range = xn - x0;
    let d = range / segments as f64;

    let sum1 = (0..segments)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|x| function(x0 + x as f64 * d) * d)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .iter()
        .sum::<f64>();

    let sum2 = (0..segments)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|x| function(x0 + x as f64 * d) * d)
        .sum::<f64>();

    println!("{} {}", sum1, sum2);
}

fn main() {
    ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
        .num_threads(3)
        .build_global()
        .unwrap();

    for _ in 0..1000 {
        integral_rayon_test(100000, 0.0, 2.0 * PI, f64::sin);
    }
}
```

There are two methods I compute the integral: `sum1` is to first collect the `par_iter` values, and then sum them up; `sum2` is to directly call `sum` on `par_iter`.

Then I run the test function `integral_rayon_test` multiple times, it produces these outputs:

```
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0.0000000000000006661338147750939
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0.0000000000000006661338147750939
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0.0000000000000006661338147750939
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 -0.0000000000000011102230246251565
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0.0000000000000006661338147750939
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0.0000000000000006661338147750939
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0.0000000000000006661338147750939
...
```

Then I have two questions:

First, I expect that `sum1` (column 1) be equal to `sum2` (column 2), but they are not.

Second, as you can see, the `sum1` numbers are all the same, but each `sum2` value has a slight difference. I also expect them to be the same. This looks like data racing, but I don't think that because rayon claims its data race free. I don't know what I'm missing.

When I change the thread number to 1, it outputs:

```
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0
-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0
...
```

where `sum2` values are the same, but still `sum1` differs from `sum2`. I don't know why.

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE**:
Test target is `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

/proc/cpuinfo shows fpu and fpu_exception true

For the second question, I just ignored that IEEE-754 floating-point numbers are not commutative, and this may be the cause.

I tested on `aarch64-linux-android` target, with thread number 1, it outputs:

```
-0.0000000000000006116797606620095 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.0000000000000006116797606620095 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.0000000000000006116797606620095 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
-0.0000000000000006116797606620095 -0.0000000000000002220446049250313
...
```

where all `sum1` and `sum2` are the same. But this result is different from the above `-0.00000000000000020519185459954437 0` output.

Can this be related to hardware floating point arithmetic? Now I have some trouble compiling the test program with `+soft-float` target feature, and cannot do some further tests.

Comment: Operations on IEEE 754 Floating-Point Numbers (`f32` and `f64`) are not commutative. The order matters.

Comment: All of these numbers are effectively zero and are well within the rounding error of floating point operations on numbers of magnitude roughly `1 / 100000`, as determined by your choice of `segments`

Comment: @PitaJ Oh yes, I just ignored it, and this makes sense. Now case 1 is okay, but for the second question (the 1-thread case), these numbers are added sequentially, but still `num1` and `num2` is not equal.

Comment: Rayon is work-stealing. The order it will execute is not necessarily in the order operations are submitted, or even deterministic.

Comment: On what hardware do you run the program? If this uses the x87 FPU (I don't remember which FPU Rust uses by default on x86-64 CPUs), then it's possible that `sum2` will do the whole computation with 80 bits of precision and only round to 64 bits at the end, whereas `sum1` will round each value to 64 bits when collecting the vector.